# How we can use alert menu before delete list items in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have list items in SwiftUI, and when I delete list items I want to delete after alert menu, like

"do want to delete your list items, ""yes" or "no"

is it possible?

```
  struct MyView: View {

    @State private var selectedUsers: MyModel?
 
    var body: some View {
        
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                
                VStack(content: {
                    
                    ForEach(datas){ data in
  
                        MyRowView(data: data)
                         
                            .contextMenu {

                                Button(action: {
                                    self.delete(item: data)
                                }) {
                                    Text("delete") 
                                }
                               
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedUsers = data
                            
                            }
                        
                    } .onDelete { (indexSet) in
                       self.datas.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                    }})
           })}

    private func delete(item data: MyModel) {
               if let index = datas.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == data.id }) {
                   datas.remove(at: index)
               }
           }}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - Add delete action (with index) to Alert button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64995209/swiftui-add-delete-action-with-index-to-alert-button)

Comment: @Yrb, I try it,but did not help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the delete action you set a `@State` bool to true, this triggers e.g. a `ConfirmationDialog` – and only after confirming there, you really delete:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var selectedUsers: MyModel?
    @State private var confirmDelete: Bool = false
    @State private var indexSet: IndexSet?
    
    @State var datas: [MyData] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                
                ForEach(datas){ data in
                    
                    MyRowView(data: data)
                        .contextMenu {
                            Button("Delete") {
                                delete(item: data)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedUsers = data
                        }
                    
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    indexSet = indexSet
                    confirmDelete = true
                }
                .confirmationDialog("Do you really want to delete?", isPresented: $confirmDelete) {
                    Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
                        selectedUsers.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                    }
                    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    private func delete(item data: IndexSet) {
        if let index = datas.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == data.id }) {
            datas.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx but I do not understand ur answer, what is @State var Bool?

Comment: in your `MyView` at the top declare a var: `@State private var confirmDelete = false`

Comment: do you want the delete confirmation for the button or for the list delete function?

Comment: it says `Cannot find 'indexSet' in scope`

Comment: for list delete

Comment: Your code is somehow not complete. You are listing `datas`– what is that? – then select on tap, and want to delete from `selectedUsers`by swipe?

Comment: so sorry yes it is datas, I update question again